# LINQ: How to group anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need to fill News object properties and collections . but i don't know what is the correct way to fill them by grouping the result.

For example how to fill properties CategoryId, CategoryName and  CommentId , CommentBody

My code looks like this:

```
var q = (
    from news in db.News
    from categories in news.Categories
    from comments in news.Comments
    where news.NewsId == 1
    select new { news.NewsId, news.NewsTitle , categories.CategoryId,categories.CategoryName , comments.CommentId, comments.CommentBody }
   ).ToList();

News ne = new News()
{
    NewsTitle = q.Select(w => w.NewsTitle).FirstOrDefault(),
    Categories = q.GroupBy(jj => jj.CategoryName).Select(vv => new Category { CategoryId, CategoryName  }).ToList(),
    Comments = q.GroupBy(ww => ww.CommentBody).Select(b => new Comment {  CommentId , CommentBody }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: Hint: currently you're not using the lambda expression parameters (`vv` and `b`)...

Comment: So you want to group by category name, and still be able to retrieve `CategoryId`?

Comment: @Caramiriel, Yes, Please help me to solve that because i am new in Linq .Thank you so much

Comment: @JonSkeet,Thank you for your help :) , Well i don't know the correct way using them Please help me to solve that problem because i am new in Linq . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of GroupBy is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TItem>>`.  This is a loopable set of groups, where each group has a Key and is itself a loopable set of source items.

```
Categories = q
  .GroupBy(jj => jj.CategoryName)
  .Select(g => new Category
  {
    CategoryId = g.First().CategoryId,
    CategoryName = g.Key
  }).ToList(),
```

Note: it is safe to call First on a group, as each group always has at least one member.